# How to save radio button selections (each with a string value) to an array of strings within a specific mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using an angular form and I want to retrieve each of the radio button selections in order to save those selections to an instance of my Picks.js mongoose model. I know I have the correct setup in terms of the Angular form and Node(Express) server, because the user._id and contest._id is saved within the mongodb database, but the selectedTeams array is saved as an empty one (selectedTeams: [ ]). I have researched for a long time through google and really cannot find anything specific as a solution for my issue. Any advise or answers would be much appreciated.

### Controller

```
function submitPicks() {
    $scope.buttonDisabled = true;
    $scope.hasMadePicks = true;
    contestService.participate(contest);
    angular.forEach($scope.contest.matchups, function(matchup) {
      $scope.selectedTeams.push(matchup.selectedTeam);
    });
    contestService.createEntry(contest._id, {
      user: authService.currentUserId(),
      selectedTeams: $scope.selectedTeams
    })
  }
```

### Service

```
function createEntry(id, pick) {
    return $http.post("/contests/" + id + "/picks", pick, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + authService.getToken()
      }
  });
}
```

### Router

```
  router.route("/contests/:contest/picks")
    .post(auth, function(req, res, next) {
      var pick = new Pick();
      pick.contest = req.contest;
      pick.save(function(err, pick) {
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        req.contest.picks.push(pick);
        req.contest.save(function(err, contest) {
          if(err) {
            return next(err);
          }
        Pick.populate(pick, {
          path: "user",
          select: "username"
        }).then(function(pick) {
          res.json(pick);
        });
      })
    })
  });
```

### HTML

```
{{contest.participants}}
{{contest.usersWhoJoined}}
<form name="contestForm" ng-submit="submitPicks()">
  <table id="nbateams">
    <tr>
      <th>Home Team</th>
      <th>Away Team</th>
      <th>Selected Team</th>
      <th>Winning Team</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="matchup in contest.matchups">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="matchup{{matchup.matchupId}}" ng-model="matchup.selectedTeam" ng-value="matchup.homeTeam">
        <img ng-src="{{matchup.homeLogo}}">
        <br>
        {{matchup.homeTeam}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="matchup{{matchup.matchupId}}" ng-model="matchup.selectedTeam" ng-value="matchup.awayTeam">
        <img ng-src="{{matchup.awayLogo}}">
        <br>
        {{matchup.awayTeam}}</td>
        <td>{{matchup.selectedTeam}}</td>
        <td>{{matchup.winningTeam}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" ng-show="!hasMadePicks" ng-disabled= "buttonDisabled" class="btn btn-success">Submit Picks</button>
</form>
{{selectedTeams}}
```

The correct string values representing each of the radio buttons values is displayed properly within the {{selectedTeams}}, I just cant get that added to the pick.selectedTeams variable within the Pick model. Here is the schema of the Pick model I keep reffering to:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PickSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  contest: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Contest"
  },
  selectedTeams: [String],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Pick', PickSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would provide an update on this just in case someone is dealt with the same issue sometime in the future.
To get the radio button selections saved within Mongodb, I made the following adjustment to the contestController:

```
contestService.createEntry(contest._id, {
  contest: $scope.contest,
  user: authService.currentUserId(),
  selectedTeams: $scope.selectedTeams
)}.success(function(pick) {
  $scope.contest.picks.push(pick);
});
}
```

And inside of the contests route:

```
router.route("/contests/:contest/picks")
.post(auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var pick = new Pick(req.body);
  pick.contestPoints = 0;

  pick.save(function(err, pick) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.contest.picks.push(pick);
    req.contest.save(function(err, contest) {
      if(err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      Pick.populate(pick, {
        path: "user",
        select: "username"
      }).then(function(pick) {
        res.json(pick);
      });
    })
  })
});
```